# IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I'm writing a code using python to generate a point shapefile within ArcMAP. I have a 1000 random possibilities of 50 points (in FileA (1000:50), and I need to try all of them.

Coordinates X of each point = FileB(:,1). Coordinates Y of each point = FileB(:,2).

to generate a sequence, i'm taking the first row of FileA, and the number in FileA(1,1) corresponds to the position in the new sequence of the point 1 in FileB

I'm trying to create a loop in which I create these sequences following the position in each row of FileA.

I have a previous post:
[AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toInteger'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335738/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-tointeger)

I changed the 'entry.toInteger()[0]' to 'int(entry[])'. Mixing languages...

I have this new error:

```
'tempXYFile.writerow('{0},{1}'.format(coordinates[int(entry)][0],coordinates[int(‌​entry)][1])) IndexError: list index out of range'
```

I'll appreciate any help !

This is my code:

```
import csv

# create 1000 XY sequences
print 'Start of the script'
sequences = csv.reader(open('50VolcanoPaleoOrder-11-01-2012.csv','rb'),delimiter=',')
coordinates = []

# read coordinates of volcanos and store in memory
print 'Start reading in the coordinates into the memory'
coordinates_file = csv.reader(open('seq50.csv','rb'),delimiter=',')   

for coordinate in coordinates[1:]:
    coordinates.append(coordinate)
del coordinates_file

i = 1
for sequence in sequences:
    print 'sequence # {0}'.format(i) 
    j = 1           
    tempXYFile = csv.writer(open('tempXY.csv','w+'),delimiter=',') #add the parameter to create a file if does not exist                  
    for entry in sequence:         
        tempXYFile.writerow('{0},{1}'.format(coordinates[int(entry)][0],coordinates[int(entry)][1]))
        print 'Entry # {0}: {1},{2}'.format(j, coordinates[int(entry)][0],coordinates[int(entry)][1]) 
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    del tempXYFile

print 'End of Script'
```

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolas\Documents\RESEARCH\AVF Voronoi sequence\Voronoi-learningprocess.py", line 38, in <module>
    tempXYFile.writerow('{0},{1}'.format(coordinates[int(entry)][0],coordinates[int(entry)][1]))
IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: Don't put it as a comment, put it into your question (formatted correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Error messages in Python aren't as impenetrable as compilation errors in certain languages; you should try to understand what they're telling you.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

is a sign that you're, well, accessing a list using an index that doesn't exist. Something like "a = [1,2]; print a[79]" would give you this message.  In this case, if the problem is in the line

```
tempXYFile.writerow('{0},{1}'.format(coordinates[int(entry)][0],coordinates[int(‌​entry)][1]))
```

then the odds are very good that either coordinates doesn't have an int(entry)-th element, or coordinates[int(entry)] doesn't have a 0th or 1st  element.

So before that line, try inserting print statements:

```
print int(entry)
print coordinates
print coordinates[int(entry)]
```

and see what isn't what you think it is.